# Virtual column definition referring to another virtual column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to have a virtual column whose column expression definition refers to another virtual column, that has previously been defined on the table? [The documentation for column expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions005.htm#SQLRF20043) says:

> the defining *column_expression* must refer only to columns of the subject table that have already been defined, in the current statement or in a prior statement

This is a simple example of what I'm trying to do, with the third virtual column referring to other *virtual* columns that have already been defined:

```
create table numberManipulation
(
  value1 VARCHAR2 (10),
  Value2 VARCHAR2 (10),
  Addition AS  (DECODE (value1, 'late', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'late', 1, 0)),
  subtraction AS(DECODE (value1, 'present', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'present', 1, 0)),
  Compile AS (ADDITION + SUBTRACTION)
);
```

But this gets error:

```
ORA-54012: virtual column is referenced in a column expression
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, although [the documentation for column expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions005.htm#SQLRF20043) doesn't explicitly say you can't. This restriction is shown in My Oracle Support document 466916.1 though, and in the [`create table` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54467):

> The column_expression in the AS clause has the following restrictions:
>
> - It cannot refer to another virtual column by name.
>     ...

You would have to repeat the calculation from each of the previous virtual columns in the third one:

```
create table numberManipulation
(
  value1 VARCHAR2 (10),
  Value2 VARCHAR2 (10),
  Addition AS  (DECODE (value1, 'late', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'late', 1, 0)),
  subtraction AS(DECODE (value1, 'present', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'present', 1, 0)),
  Compile AS (DECODE (value1, 'late', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'late', 1, 0)
    + DECODE (value1, 'present', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'present', 1, 0))
);

Table NUMBERMANIPULATION created.
```

Or slightly more simply:

```
  Compile AS (DECODE (value1, 'late', 1, 'present', 1, 0)
    + DECODE (value2, 'late', 1, 'present', 1, 0))
```

... though you may prefer to keep the two longer expressions matching the earlier columns for consistency and maintenance.

Having one virtual column refer to another would dictate the order they had to be evaluated, and could lead to circular dependencies.

An alternative is to have a view that calculates the final column from the two virtual columns in the base table:

```
create table numberManipulation
(
  value1 VARCHAR2 (10),
  Value2 VARCHAR2 (10),
  Addition AS  (DECODE (value1, 'late', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'late', 1, 0)),
  subtraction AS(DECODE (value1, 'present', 1, 0) + DECODE (value2, 'present', 1, 0))
);

Table NUMBERMANIPULATION created.

create view vNumberManipulation as
select numberManipulation.*, addition + subtraction as compile
from numberManipulation;

View VNUMBERMANIPULATION created.

insert into numberManipulation (value1, value2) values ('late', 'late');
insert into numberManipulation (value1, value2) values ('late', 'present');
insert into numberManipulation (value1, value2) values ('present', null);
select * from vNumberManipulation;

VALUE1     VALUE2        ADDITION  SUBTRACTION      COMPILE
---------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ------------
late       late                 2            0            2
late       present              1            1            2
present                         0            1            1
```

A view also can't reference its own columns so you still need the addition and subtraction in the base table. You could also have an [`instead-of` trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041) on the view so that attempting to modify the view actually changes the base table, which would make it a bit more user-friendly.

Comment: thanks but the problem is that, i give here was like sample, there is usually value1 ..... value28, is there other ways to do that as it will be more complicated to type too much

Comment: You could have a view that calculates a column value based on the virtual columns of the base table; if necessary with an instead-of trigger. Or you could have a physical column that's set via a trigger, but that's not ideal either.

Comment: o.. is there any reference or key point i can search based on it.

Comment: @Programmer - I've added the view version and a link to instead-of triggers.

Comment: thanks, but stated insufficient privilages, is there a way to solve it when i tried to create view.

Comment: @Programmer - your DBA would need to give you `create view` privileges. (And maybe `create trigger` if you don't already have it, and want to do that part).

Comment: A DBA account has to grant it, if you are your own DBA (you have access to SYS) then you can grant it from that to your normal user. Otherwise no, that would make the privileges a bit pointless, if you give grant things to yourself.

Comment: sir, i would like really thanks you for helping me and giving such a briliant idea. Thanks sir alot.